# How to have shadow enabled in hover and select of highmap?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to have an effect like this when I hover over or select a country

[hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8g7L.png)

Ignore the tooltip present here

Answer (score 2):

You can add this functionality in your point.mouseOver and point.mouseOut events callback functions.

You can use point.graphic.shadow() for adding shadow to your point and then remove this shadow manually on mouseOut.

Here you can see code that may help you:

```
   point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          this.graphic.shadow({
            width: 10
          })
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          Highcharts.each(this.graphic.shadows, function(p) {
            p.remove();
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

And here you can find live example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/x4j0d6dy/1/

Regards,